# In Django rest framework: GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db '

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, gdal

I am using the versions for my project:

```
Django==2.2.7
djangorestframework==3.10.3
mysqlclient==1.4.5
```

In my database I work with geometric types, and for this I have configured the library: GDAL-3.0.2-cp38-cp38-win32

To run this library, I have to include these variables in the django properties file:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now on my models, I do the following import:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

For types like:

```
coordinates = models.GeometryField (db_column = 'Coordinates', blank = True, null = True)
```

It seems that the queries work correctly, but when creating a new element, I get the following error:

```
GDAL_ERROR 1: b'PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db '
```

But after this error, the object is persisted correctly in the database.

I would like to know how to solve this error.

I have not found information on the network, I have only tried to declare a new variable in the DJANGO properties file:

```
PROJ_LIB = 'APP / backend / env / Lib / site-packages / osgeo / data / proj / proj.db'
```

But the error still appears, and you may have problems in the production environment in an OpenSuse image

Why can't you find proj.db?
How do I solve it?

Comment: PROJ_LIB must point the proj.db directory, in your case : PROJ_LIB = 'APP/backend/ env/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/data/proj

Comment: Hello, I have done the test you comment, with the same result.

Comment: Maybe your variable is not handled as an environment variable ? Did you try to set PROJ_LIB in a terminal : > export PROJ_LIB='/your/path/proj' ?

Comment: (without quotes) > export PROJ_LIB=/your/path/proj

Comment: hello jsiot without quotes, result: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, I realize you work on Windows (GDAL-3.0.2-cp38-cp38-win32); have you tried to include PROJ_LIB as environnement variable using (setx or via Conrol Panel) ? don't forget to use "\" instead of "/" ; the problem will not be solved for OpenSuse :(